# Xcode Iphone Simulator turn Landscape

Tags: ios-simulator, landscape, autorotate, portrait, landscape-portrait

my iPhone App includes 2 view-orientations: portrait and landscape.
It starts in portrait, but includes 2 view controllers, which should rotate **automatically** to landscape.

Thats my code in the landscape-views:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

But when the view loads in the iPhone-simulator, the virtual device stays in portrait, and the content of the landscape-view isn't displayed correctly. 
I have to turn the device **manually**(simulator).

Can you give me a solution for my problem?
Or is it only a problem with the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in your info.plist the initial interface orientation - this ought to get your app launching in the correct orientation.  Look for a line called `Initial interface orientation`.

Or, if you can't find that line, add this line to your info.plist:

`UIInterfaceOrientation` with the value: (String) `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`

Hope that helps.

Comment: The app launches in portrait. correctly!
But the switch from portrait to landscape doesn't work. i have to turn the simulator manually

Comment: Oh I see - so you want to programatically rotate the simulator to match your rotated view controllers? I'm afraid it doesn't work that way :(  They built the simulator to emulate as closely as possible what your app would do on a real device.  `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is a method for handling the device changing orientation in the real world. Therefor, it's impossible to have your code change the orientation of the device - just imagine that in the real world and you'll see why.  So, to answer your question, I'm afraid you'll have to manually rotate the simulator each time.

Comment: Do you mean that the code must be wrong or that the simulator doesn't work well?
When the app is in use, the user shouldn't have to turn the device every time to see the whole content of the landscape views. (turn landscape before reading)

Comment: I guess to go along with the design you're describing, it's that the simulator doesn't handle that. In the real world, when you flip the content of your app into landscape view, your user will intuitively turn the device to match (i.e., manually). In the simulator, that action is still manual in that it requires you to press a button.